# how to remove brush stroke overlay from a picture mainly comprise of text

Tags: stroke, brush, overlay

I am not a professional graphic designer but I have an issue to resolve and needs pro advice

I have some text written in picture format and it has brushstroke overlays in red color hiding the text. I want to remove those overlays to read the full text - is there any way I can peel them off.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry but that's usually not possible, unless you have a layered image format such as a PSD, and then only if the text is on a layer below the brush strokes.

Answer (score 1):

Digital images do not work like they do on fictitious tv shows like CSI. Media will often do things which are actually impossible in real life. Digital images are **flat**. They don't contain "layers" of one items covering another. In other words, they are more like a jigsaw puzzle where pieces interlock with each other, not a layer cake where pieces overlap each other.

If you have a digital image with text that is covered, you **can't** merely remove the covering color to see the text.

The **only** possible way to see the text is if it's *slightly* visible even though another color is across it - in this case you would *still* be able to read the text. However, if the text is completely obliterated, it can't be "restored" in any way.